# CSS float left divs go underneath with smaller screen resolution

Tags: css

I have two divs, they look like this:

```
<div style="float:left;">blah</div>
<div>blah1</div>
```

In screen resolution x, these appear as planned like so:

> blah    blah1

However, in screen resolution less than x, these appear like so:

> blah
>
> blah1

This is a width error. How can I get my divs to adjust the width so this doesn't happen? My widths are set as percents, not as fixed pixels lengths.

NOTE: If possible, I need a way to fix this with auto widths. The content changes per page, so I cannot set even percent widths.... Unless ABSOLUTELY necessary!!

Comment: Use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a margin on the second `div`:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<div style='float:left;width:200px;background:yellow'>First Div</div>

<div style='margin-left:200px;background:orange'>Second Div</div>

</body></html>
```

...and it will fill all the extra space, every time.

---

The markup above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What if the widths are percents? Same thing? Then what if the width is auto set? Then how can I do this?

Comment: Percents should work the same.  Auto set will not (like in your code sample).  There's not another way (that I know of) to handle a liquid horizontal layout that mixes float and non-floating elements, without specifying width.

Comment: I just tried this with a percent and it still fell underneath.

Comment: Just tested and % width works as expected.  The padding or margin of your elements may be making the element wider than you think.